# Wordpress Submenu Getting Cut Off

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

Inherited a educational organization website and running into an issue with a dropdown submenu getting clipped by an inner-content div. It looks like there is a z-index of 100 for that inner-content div, but no matter what I set the submenu z-index to I can't get it to layer over the div.

The menu item that is getting clipped is Connect > Interest Section (IS) > *Clipped Menu (there should be 5 visible links).

The organization URL is http://minnetesol.org/.

[Clipped subnav element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRwho.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the following it will work but there is more at play in the styles then z-index:-

```
#main-nav ul ul li ul {
    left: 250px;
    top: -50px;
}

#content {
    margin: 0 auto -40px;
}
```

You would need to tweak the logo in the header after making these changes.

Comment: Looks like this will work. I'll dink around with the logo to even things out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a z-indexing issue - #content #inner-content has a z-index of 100, so you'll need to do

```
#head{
  z-index: 101;
}
```

I'd also recommend lowering your #inner-content z-index to 1 and #head to 2 just to prevent more z-index issues in the future.

Comment: Setting the #head to a z-index of 101 gets the subnav to appear but it overlaps the #inner-content section with the featured blog posts. Any way to leave #inner-content and #head as they are and have the navigational elements as the top layer?

Comment: The subnav need to overlap everything else when you have it open, otherwise it gets covered/cut off by #inner-content